# how to visualize box plot using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to visualize a box plot using pandas default utilities like as given bellow.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.read_csv('out.tsv',sep='\t')
>>> df
  Unnamed: 0  specificity  sensitivity  presison   mcc    f1
0         LR         1.00         0.00      0.00  0.00  0.00
1        GNB         0.70         0.90      0.72  0.63  0.76
2        KNB         0.65         0.63      0.73  0.30  0.63
3         DT         0.70         0.70      0.72  0.45  0.66
4         SV         1.00         0.00      0.00  0.00  0.00
>>> df.boxplot()
```

It returns Object, insteed of plot:

```
<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x7fe319bf5b90>
```

how can I visualize this plot?

Thank you.

Comment: If you're using a Jupyter notebook, add (& run) the `%matplotlib inline` directive before calling boxplot

Comment: No its not in Jupyter.

Comment: Then try: `import matplotlib; matplotlib.interactive(True)`

Comment: Thanks,  your solution works.

Comment: To show a matplotlib plot you need to (in general) call `plt.show()`.

Comment: I already tried this 'plt.show()', after and without importing matplotlib but it was not working. But @rdas suggestion worked perfectly.

Comment: In that case something is not set up correctly. Meaning, to rely on `plt.ion()` (or `interactive`) might cause other problems in the future.